# Adding a column in multiple csv file using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I want to add a column at the multiple (500) CSV files (same dimensionality). Each column should act as an identifier for the individual file. I want to create a bash script using awk(I am a new bee in awk). The CSV files do come with headers.

For eg. 
Input `File1.csv`

```
 #name,#age,#height
 A,12,4.5
 B,13,5.0
```

Input `File2.csv`

```
 #name,#age,#height
 C,11,4.6
 D,12,4.3
```

I want to add a new column "#ID" in both the files, where the value of ID will be same for an individual file but not for both the file.

Expected Output
`File1.csv`

```
 #name,#age,#height,#ID
 A,12,4.5,1
 B,13,5.0,1
```

Expected `File2.csv`

```
 #name,#age,#height,#ID
 C,11,4.6,2
 D,12,4.3,2
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to extract the id number from the filename, this should do.

```
$ c=1; for f in File*.csv; 
  do 
     sed -i '1s/$/,#ID/; 2,$s/$/,'$c'/' "$f"; 
     c=$((c+1)); 
  done
```

note that this is inplace edit.  Perhaps make a backup or test first.

**UPDATE**
If you don't need the individual files to be updated, this may work better for you

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'BEGIN  {f="allFiles.csv"} 
                FNR==1 {c++; print $0,"#ID" > f; next} 
                       {print $0,c > f}' File*.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I indeed don't need to extract the id from the filename. I want to add a column so that once I concatenate all the CSV files, I would be able to differentiate the data points/files via the #ID column. I tried running the script you shared but it throws an error "invalid command code J".

Comment: This is MacOS sed quirk. It forces you to specify backup name after `-i`.

Comment: So after adding a backup file credential, the output edits in all csv files I am getting is: The column 2,3,4 got a header named "#ID,#ID, ID" in row 2. Also, a new alternate row '1,1,incrementing value" is added under column 2,3,4.

Comment: I'm sorry don't have access to MacOS to verify.  It works fine on Linux.  Perhaps `awk` is a better solution here...

Comment: I do need all the files updated with a new column header named #ID which maintains a constant ID number as item (like file 1 -> ID 1, file 2 -> ID and so on). I would be really helpful if you can explain the role of "{f="allFiles.csv"} " is in the awk code. So far, when I run awk code, it doesn't do anything to any csv file.

Comment: `awk` should generate the file "allFiles.csv" where all the contents of the files are combined with the corresponding ID columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, ‘
    FNR == 1 {
        $(NF + 1) = “ID#”
        i++
        f = FILENAME
        sub(/Input/, “Output”, f)
    } FNR != 1 {
        $(NF + 1) = i
    } {
        print > f
    }’ Input*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for inplace editing and ARGIND:

```
awk -i inplace -v OFS=, '{print $0, (FNR==1 ? "#ID" : ARGIND)}' File*.csv
```

Comment: This assumes that the files are sequential, but it also assumes that a glob will produce a numeric sort. I believe globs sort lexically, which would mean that ARGIND would not match the file number.  (i.e. FILE11.CSV comes before FILE2.CSV.)

Comment: The OP didn't say she needed the numbers to match the file names, just that it had to be unique. We don't even know if her input files are really named File1.csv, etc. - those are probably just names she made up for the [mcve].

Comment: We also don't know that the numbers *don't* need to match the filenames. I didn't say it was a bad answer, but with the lack of detailed requirements, it's good to note environmental factors which might affect the behaviour of your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response everyone.Much appreciated.  The input file names cited here are "made-up" ones. I just need a unique name ID for an individual file. But it won't do any harm to know how to have the original file name as "unique identity" too.

Comment: replace ARGIND with FILENAME